# Azure Durable Function with Orchestrator Trigger is Initiated Prematurely When Restarting the Function App and causing Exception

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an `Azure Durable Function` (`.NET 7 Isolated Worker Process Durable Function`) whose entry point is an `HttpTrigger`. It makes a call to an `Orchestrator Function`, which calls a few different `Activity Functions`. I'm running this function app locally as it's still in testing/development but I've noticed one thing happening that's problematic. When I stop the `Function App` while it's in the `Orchestrator Function` logic and restart it, it goes right back into the logic of the Orchestration Function (I have breakpoints set up so it hits the first one). But, it hasn't been called by the `HttpTrigger` function. I figure it still has this `orchestrator function id` in memory and picks up where it left off.

When it hits the first `Activity Function`, it throws an unknown exception (the `Activity Function` throws it), but the catch statement's `Exception` parameter is `null` (never seen that). **EDIT** - The `Exception` parameter in the `Catch` block is null, but the console shows this:

```
 Exception of type 'DurableTask.Core.Exceptions.TaskFailedException' was thrown
```

Now, the `Activity Function` that is throwing this exception doesn't have any breakpoints hit, even though I have a few in there, so it doesn't perform any logic in that function. My guess is that after stopping the whole Function App and restarting, it's starting back up with the original `Orchestration Function` that was invoked and when it tries to hit the first `Activity Function`, that's where it does something of which I don't know and throws the exception.

How can I handle this failure gracefully? By this time of failure (before actually), the `HttpTrigggered` function has already returned a 200 to the front end so the user won't know what's going on.

If something happens and this unknown exception is thrown/caught, is that particular invocation of the `Orchestrator Function` discarded? I assume no because it picks back up (or maybe with a new function invocation). I've hit this exception, continued through it (that's the end of the Function App) and tried to send another request to start the process over. But, I get the same unknown exception when I step through and reach the code that initializes the `Activity Function` (a call to `CallActivityAsync`), even though it never actually enters that function (well no breakpoints are hit inside of it, maybe more advanced stuff is going on). **EDIT**: `Exception` is:

```
 Exception of type 'DurableTask.Core.Exceptions.TaskFailedException' was thrown
```

I'm at a loss as I don't know when this `Exception` could be thrown in production and want it to fail gracefully. Has anyone come across anything like this and know an appropriate way to handle a situation like this so the user can retry? I can try and rustle up some code to show the flow I described above, but wanted to see if anyone had come across something like this.

Answer (score 1):

When we run Azure durable functions, it creates queues and containers in the Storage account which function app is using. So when the client triggers the orchestration function, it stores the information in storage, so even if we stop or restart the function, when orchestration is still running it doesn't delete the info from the storage account. That is why the function app starts again, it picks the state from the storage account.

I also ran into the same issues while local development, so I usually manually delete the containers and queue and when the function app is restarted, it will be created again.

This won't be a scenario in the production, because the function app won't be restarted during the execution of orchestration functions and even if it happens we need to do the same. I don't think Microsoft has provided any other way to handle this situation.

Comment: I read about this saving of function info in storage, but I ran this same FA maybe a month ago and never ran into this issue. There are some new tweaks to service registration in the FA but I wouldn't imagine it would cause this unless it changes the storage resources, but definitely something I will check out. Let me check in the morning (quite late here) and if that solves the issue I will mark it as correct. Thank you for your insight!